# Mouse Selection in MASM32

Tags: assembly, mouseclick-event, masm32, irvine32

Ultimately, I am trying to select a button when there is a left click on the mouse using assembly language but have not found any useful techniques. Any help would be grateful! The code for the program is below.

```
INCLUDE IRVINE32.inc
INCLUDELIB kernel32.lib
INCLUDELIB user32.lib
INCLUDELIB Winmm.lib
INCLUDELIB Windows.lib
INCLUDELIB kernel32.lib
INCLUDELIB gdi32.lib



WinMain proto :DWORD,:DWORD,:DWORD,:DWORD
ExitProcess PROTO STDCALL :DWORD

WM_LBUTTONDOWN EQU 0x0201

.data
prompt BYTE "Mouse Not Pressed",0
message BYTE "Mouse pressed",0
MouseClick db 0
WM_LBUTTONDOWN bytE 0x0201



.code
main PROC 
mov edx, OFFSET message
.IF WM_LBUTTONDOWN == true
Call WriteString
.ENDIF
mov edx, OFFSET prompt
Call WriteString

invoke ExitProcess, 0
main ENDP
END main
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [MichaelW](http://www.masmforum.com/board/index.php?topic=4512.msg33715#msg33715) I could build an example for your needs:

```
include irvine32.inc

.data

    hStdIn    dd 0
    nRead     dd 0

    _INPUT_RECORD STRUCT
        EventType   WORD ?
        WORD ?                    ; For alignment
        UNION
            KeyEvent              KEY_EVENT_RECORD          <>
            MouseEvent            MOUSE_EVENT_RECORD        <>
            WindowBufferSizeEvent WINDOW_BUFFER_SIZE_RECORD <>
            MenuEvent             MENU_EVENT_RECORD         <>
            FocusEvent            FOCUS_EVENT_RECORD        <>
          ENDS
    _INPUT_RECORD ENDS

    InputRecord _INPUT_RECORD <>

    ConsoleMode dd 0
    Msg db "Click! ",0
    Msg2 db "Esc ",0

.code

main PROC
    invoke GetStdHandle,STD_INPUT_HANDLE
    mov   hStdIn,eax

    invoke GetConsoleMode, hStdIn, ADDR ConsoleMode
    mov eax, 0090h          ; ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT | DISABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE | ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS
    invoke SetConsoleMode, hStdIn, eax

    .WHILE InputRecord.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode != VK_ESCAPE

        invoke ReadConsoleInput,hStdIn,ADDR InputRecord,1,ADDR nRead

        movzx  eax,InputRecord.EventType
        cmp eax, MOUSE_EVENT
        jne no_mouse
        test InputRecord.MouseEvent.dwButtonState, 1
        jz no_mouse

        lea edx, Msg
        Call WriteString
        jmp done

        no_mouse:
    .ENDW

    lea edx, Msg2
    Call WriteString

    done:
    mov eax, ConsoleMode
    invoke SetConsoleMode, hStdIn, eax
    call ReadChar
    invoke ExitProcess, 0
main ENDP

end main
```

Comment: Removed my last comment, I thought the alignment issue had been fixed quite some time back.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Do you mean [this one](http://www.masmforum.com/board/index.php?topic=7872)? It seems that it is fixed in masm32v11r/windows.inc as well as in irvine32.inc/smallwin.inc. But the local declaration makes the example more clear :-)

Comment: Fair enough. I removed my comment because I realized that it is better safer than sorry since no revision was mentioned. I am your upvoter.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thank you for the example. This opens my understanding greatly.

Comment: @user5577817 : I wasn't the kind soul who helped you - rkhb was. If this answer helped you, please consider accepting the answer. More on how to accept and why, please see this SO information: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/271768

Comment: @Michael Petch Thank you! Still new to this website.

Comment: @rkhb Thank you very much !!

Comment: @user5577817 Not a problem and Welcome!